# Making a program to detect if a word is a palindrome (ignoring capitalization)

Tags: python

I have trouble making this program because I don't know how to make it so the program will ignore capitalization. I used .lower but I think I'm inserting it wrong.

```
word=input("Give me a word to detect if it is a palindrome")
word=str(word)

if word.lower[::-1]=word :
    print("That's a palindrome")
else:
    print("Sorry this isn't a palindrome")
```

Comment: You have to lower *both* sides of the comparison.

Comment: You aren't checking if the words are equal to each other. One equal is setting a value to a variable, which is impossible. You need two equals instead

Comment: ``word[::-1].lower() == word.lower()``

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word=input("Give me a word to detect if it is a palindrome: ")
word_list = word.split()
for i in word_list:
   if i.lower()[::-1]==i.lower() and len(i) > 1:
      print("That's a palindrome")
   else:
      print("Sorry this isn't a palindrome")
```

This will detect all palindromes and if you want only one word as input, remove the for loop.

Comment: Why ask for a single word and then split that word into... words?

Comment: I did mention that if he needs a single word input he can get rid of the for loop and use word input instead